# How to get specific data from output of the command run through c?

Tags: c, cmd

`system("netsh wlan show profile");`

I executed this cmd using c program now, i want all profile names shown in the output
and save it in variable(array). How to do that also please tell me in detailed because i don't have knowledge of c, i am trying to learning it.

Comment: `system` only runs a command and gives you its exit status. To get the actual output of the program read about the [`popen`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) function (or [`_popen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/popen-wpopen?view=msvc-170) on Windows).

Answer (score 5):

Use [popen](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *str = "netsh wlan show profile";
    FILE *cmd;

#ifdef _WIN32
    cmd = _popen(str, "r");
#elif __unix
    cmd = popen(str, "r");
#else
#   error "Unknown system"
#endif
    if (cmd == NULL)
    {
        perror("popen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char result[1024];

    while (fgets(result, sizeof(result), cmd))
    {
        printf("output: %s", result);
    }
#ifdef _WIN32
    _pclose(cmd);
#elif __unix
    pclose(cmd);
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you declare the `popen` and `pclose` functions? Both they and the Windows `_popen` and `_pclose` are declared in the `stdio.h` header file. You should not declare them yourself.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude without a prototype gcc is warning: `warning: implicit declaration of function ‘popen’` (at least on Linux)

Comment: With MS VC it's `_popen()` and `_pclose()` because they are not Standard C functions.

Comment: You really get the warnings when building on Linux? That's very odd. [The official POSIX documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html) quite clearly states that it should be declared in `<stdio.h>`. And I can't replicate it on my own (on different systems).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, yes, really, the warning is introduced by `-Wimplicit-function-declaration` and I compile with `gcc -std=c11 -Wpedantic -Wall -Wextra`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Probably compiling in strict cNN mode instead of gnuNN, which disables most things that aren't in the C standard.

Comment: @DavidRanieri Yup, there's the issue. Use `-std=gnu11` or `#define` the appropriate feature test macro before any includes.

Comment: @Shawn  thats a good advise, thanks!